# TypoScript Content if no result use another query

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

i have a simple typoscript that works wonderfull, it selects the next page from the current one

```
lib.refnext = COA
lib.refnext{
    stdWrap.required = 1
    10 = CONTENT
    10{
        table = pages
        select{
            pidInList.dataWrap = {field:pid}
            where.dataWrap = sorting<{field:sorting}
            begin = 0
            max = 1
            orderBy = sorting DESC
        }
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj{
            10 = TEXT
            10.typolink.parameter.field = uid
            10.typolink.ATagParams = class="next"
            10.value = nächste Referenz
        }
    }
}
```

with required=1 the wrap is not rendered if the select returns no result (current page is the newest page), now i want to show a Content with another select statement. i tried it with

```
20 = CONTENT
20.if.isFalse < .10
```

but there was no output. the select must else look like:

```
select{
    pidInList.dataWrap = {field:pid}
    begin = 0
    max = 1
    orderBy = sorting ASC
}
```

(the first page and not the next from the current) how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

One problem that you have in your question is that `20.if.isFalse` is evaluated as a string, not as a content object. So if you do `20.if.isFalse` then your evaluated TS will look roughly like this (**CARE, FOLLOWING TS MAKES NO SENSE!**):

```
20.if.isFalse = CONTENT
20.if.isFalse {
   table = pages
   [...]
}
```

And of course the string `"CONTENT"` never evaluates to false. Also, the TS makes no sense, because `isFalse` has no `table` property, no `select` property etc.

But `20.if.isFalse` *does* have stdWrap properties, so you can simply do it as `20.if.isFalse.cObject < .10`. That should work.

It then evaluates to this, which actually **does** make sense:

```
20.if.isFalse.cObject = CONTENT
20.if.isFalse.cObject {
   table = pages
   [...]
}
```

Comment: i tried this but the the 20.if.isFalse.cObject = CONTENT does not evaluated

Answer (score 0):

As @Matmarbon already mentioned you need to use `cObject` for your `isFalse`.

Another option to fill an empty property is the function `ifEmpty`. Here you also need `cObject` (to define the replacement) but you should be faster as there is no copy of `.10` which needs a further evaluation.
Probably you also need no `COA`.

So this might result in a structure like

```
lib.refnext = CONTENT
lib.refnext{
    required = 1
    table = pages
    select{
        pidInList.dataWrap = {field:pid}
        where.dataWrap = sorting<{field:sorting}
        begin = 0
        max = 1
        orderBy = sorting DESC
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj{
        typolink.parameter.field = uid
        typolink.ATagParams = class="next"
        value = nächste Referenz
    }

    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = CONTENT
    stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {

        // alternative content selection and rendering

    }
}
```

Comment: this looks very clean and is my favorite, but the ifEmpty.cObject does not evaluated

Comment: sometimes it helps to add a `.stdWrap` before a function. Try `stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject` (and make sure that there is content inside). (use `stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT` and `stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject.value = in ifEmpty` for testing)

Comment: I added it to my answer.